# Downloading a file created from console output in PuTTY

Tags: putty

So my class Project3 prints a load of data to the console of PuTTY when I run it, and I've used "java Project3 > variance.data" to create the file variance.data in the pwd.

I think this has worked because when i use "ls" variance.data is there.

However I want to save this file onto my computer, how do I do this?

Comment: Hi Owen, do you want to do it automatically when the file is created? Or you can do it manually? A suggestion, give more information on the task, for example what are you connected with through PuTTY.

Comment: PuTTY also comes with psftp. Can you use that?

Comment: I was under the impression I could could do it manually in PuTTY fairly easily? I'm connected to my university computer system with PuTTY

Comment: @MikeHarris what is a psftp and how do I use that?

Comment: can't download files with telnet, Get WinSCP and you can download files (FTP Client or SSH Client), download files using SFTP

Comment: @SSpoke I already have WinSCP, but even though the file appears when I use ls, it is the only file that doesn't appear in WinSCP!!

Comment: Have you tried renaming the file to something like `.txt` instead of `.data` it should appear in WinSCP regardless.  Run this command in PuTTY  `find / -name "variance.data"` maybe its in a different folder that's why you can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PuTTy Secure Copy to download the file.

Open CMD on your Windows machine and use the following command:

```
pscp <user>@<Remote Server IP>:/path/to/file .
```

You will then be prompted for the password of the user you are trying to connect as.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) to connect to the server with your credential (the one you use with PuTTY) and then download the file you need only double-clicking on it. In the image you'll fine it in the 5th rectangle. At the same way, you can easily upload a file double-clicking on in the 4th rectangle.

[image]